# Error in Exploding variables with Specail Characters

Tags: php, special-characters, explode

```
$html = file_get_contents('abc.com/abc');
// create document object model
$dom = new DOMDocument();
// load html into document object model
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
// create domxpath instance
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom);
// get all elements with a particular id and then loop through and print the href attribute
$elements = $xPath->query("//*[@class='f16']");
foreach ($elements as $e) {
  $str = $e->nodeValue;
}
$values = explode("A", $str);
echo $values[0];
```

Returns "`Data1 Â Data2 Â  Data 3`"

But it works fine when,

```
$values = explode("Â", "Data1 Â Data2 Â  Data 3");
echo $values[0];
```

Returns "`Data1`"

How to solve this ?

Comment: Works fine for me! See: http://3v4l.org/WQeMQ

Comment: `UTF-8`; 1. Make sure you show us your **full** and **real** code! 2. Also add error reporting: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` to the top of your file(s) an thell us if you get any

Comment: How are you wanting the data to be outputted? Could you provide a text example please

Comment: `Â` !== `A` So why would you expect that if you set the delimiter to `A` that it would match anywhere in this string: `Data1 Â Data2 Â  Data 3` ?

Comment: $values = explode(chr(194), $str); Works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found it.

```
$values = explode(chr(194), $str);
```

Because it is encode in ANSI.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to return all of the data then you can use foreach as below:

```
<?php
$str = "Data1 Â Data2 Â  Data 3";
$values = explode("Â", $str);

foreach($values as $index=>$value) {
echo "$index - $value<br>";
}

?>
```

Returns:

```
0 - Data1
1 - Data2
2 - Data 3
```

Comment: No explanation why OP's code fails. Also as the second example works for OP it seems like he just wants to get the first value of the exploded array! So he doesn't need a foreac loop!

Comment: @Rizier123 It looks to me like the OP is trying to return all data and does not realise that the explode stores data in an array. We need some more information from the OP on what he is trying to achieve

Comment: 1. *But it works fine when* ... *Returns "Data1"* <- So pretty obviously OP wants the first array element! 2. *does not realise that the explode stores data in an array* What? `echo $values[0];` This doesn't looks like he's trying to access an array element?! 3. *We need some more information from the OP* Then use the comments if you need more informations, don't say that to me

Comment: @Rizier123 I dont think the hostility is necessary, 1. Why would you assume he wants the first value when he hasn't said that? 2. Yes he is accessing the array value but who is to say he didn't copy that code from somewhere and doesn't necessarily understand it.

Comment: In the original question the explode did not fail, i just showed him a way that would give him full access to the data as he did not provide enough information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76184/discussion-between-polaris-and-rizier123).